# Formatting output using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I've a file with following content:

```
A 28713.64                  27736.1000
B 9835.32
C 38548.96
```

Now, i need to check if the last row in the first column is 'C', then the value of first row in third column should be printed in the third column against 'C'.

Expected Output:

```
A 28713.64                  27736.1000
B 9835.32
C 38548.96                  27736.1000
```

I tried below, but it's not working:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "C") ; print $1,$2,$3}' file_name
```

Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: `...then i want to print the same value which is there in third column.` from which row? always the first row? or the last not-zero/empty value?

Comment: @Kent: yes, always the first row of third column.

Comment: Your requirements aren't clear - do you need to modify any/every row that starts with C as $1 or do you need to modify the 3rd row IF that specific row starts with C or do you need to modify the 3rd row regardless of it's $1 value or something else? If the 3rd/C-row already has a value in the 3rd field should that be changed or left alone?

Comment: @EdMorton: I need to modify the row which has string 'C' in it , and my file would always contains only one 'C' in the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for the given example:

```
awk 'NR==1{v=$3}$1=="C"{$0=$0 FS v}7' file|column -t
```

If you want to append the 3rd column value from `A` row to `C` row, change `NR==1` into `$1=="A"`

The `column -t` part is just for making output pretty. :-)

Comment: Can you please explain the above awk command. Would be helpful!!! Thanks.

Comment: Erm... `7`?  :-D

Comment: @A.K if the current row is the first, save `$3` in var `v`. if `$1=="C"`, add the `v` to the end of the line, then print the current row.

Comment: @ghoti the non-zero number does awk's default action: `print`

Comment: @ghoti, condition should be TRUE(non-zero number or other words if something is NOT zero in short condition here), either it is `7` or `1` or `100` :) usually IMHO people put `1` so that it will be easily understandable that we are putting `1` to make condition TRUE :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 you are right, personally I prefer right index finger better than left little finger. :D

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** As per OP's comment OP is looking for very first line and looking to match `C` string at very last line of Input_file, if this is the case then one should try following.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  value=$NF
  print
  next
}
prev{
  print prev
}
{
  prev=$0
  prev_first=$1
}
END{
  if(prev_first=="C"){
      print prev,value
  }
  else{
      print
  }
}'  file | column -t
```

---

---

Assuming that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples and you want to pick value from 1st column whose value is `A`.

```
awk '$1=="A" && FNR==1{value=$NF} $1=="C"{print $0,value;next} 1' Input_file| column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A  28713.64  27736.1000
B  9835.32
C  38548.96  27736.1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working. But here, i'm not considering the value of first row in 1st column i.e 'A'. I just want to check if the last row in the first column is 'C', then the value of first row in third column should be printed in the third column against 'C'.

Comment: @A.K, please check my EDIT solution, it only checks last line's C if C is not there then it will simply print the line, check and let me know then?

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks:-)

Answer (score 2):

POSIX dictates that "*assigning to a nonexistent field (for example, $(NF+2)=5) shall increase the value of NF; create any intervening fields with the uninitialized value; and cause the value of $0 to be recomputed, with the fields being separated by the value of OFS.*"

So...

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$3} $1=="C"{$3=x} 1' input.txt
```

Note that the output is not formatted well, but that's likely the case with most of the solutions here. You could pipe the output through [`column`](http://man.freebsd.org/column), as Ravinder suggested. Or you could control things precisely by printing your data with `printf`.

```
awk 'NR==1{x=$3} $1=="C"{$3=x} {printf "%-2s%-26s%s\n",$1,$2,$3}' input.txt
```

If your lines can be expressed in a `printf` format, you'll be able to avoid the unpredictability of `column -t` and save the overhead of a pipe.